# Symfony 5: incorrectly returned page content

Tags: symfony5

after multiple research I come to ask for your help.

I created several pages in my symfony project, this my controller code:

```
public function liste(Request $request){
    $users = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(VicidialUsers::class)
    ->findAll();

    return $this->render('user/list_users.html.twig', array(
        'users' => $users
    ));
}

public function nouveau(Request $request): Response
{
    $user = new VicidialUsers();
    $form = $this->createForm(VicidialUsersType::class , $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
            ->add('notice', 'L\'utilisateur à été bien ajouter');
        //clear form values after successful form submission
        unset($user);
        unset($form);
        $user = new VicidialUsers();
        $form = $this->createForm(VicidialUsersType::class , $user);
    }

    return $this->render('user/adduser.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}

public function edit(Request $request , $userId){

    $user = new VicidialUsers();
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository
    (VicidialUsers::class)->find($userId);
    $form = $this->createForm(VicidialUsersType::class , $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
            ->add('notice', 'L\'utilisateur a été bien modifier');
    }

    return $this->render('user/edituser.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView() ,'user' => $user
    ));
}
```

Only problem the page returned incorrectly in the case of editing or adding a new user

This is the user list display:
127.0.0.1:8000/utilisateurs:

[![User List][1]][1]

in the case of edit: 127.0.0.1:8000/user/edit/3:

the template  is returned incorrectly

[![Edit User][2]][2]

This is my template code for `adduser.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig'%}

{% block body %} 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Ajouter un nouvel utilisateur</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>{{ flashMessage }}</h4>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- general form elements -->
    
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <!-- form start -->
        <form method="post">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ form_label(form.user) }}</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.user) }}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.user) }}</span>
                            <div id="notification"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ form_label(form.pass) }}</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.pass) }}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.pass) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ form_label(form.fullName) }}</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.fullName) }}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.fullName) }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>                             
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ form_label(form.userLevel) }}</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.userLevel) }}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.userLevel) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ form_label(form.userGroup) }}</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.userGroup) }}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.userGroup) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ form_label(form.phoneLogin) }}</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.phoneLogin) }}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.phoneLogin) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{ form_label(form.phonePass) }}</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.phonePass) }}
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.phonePass) }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            {{ form_rest(form) }}
            <div class="box-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ajouter" />
            </div>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The form is transmitted to the template, but the template doesn't format correctly the data. I'd say the problem would rather be on the template side. But difficult to say without the code of your template ; don't hesitate to add it to your question.

Comment: thank you i add the template code to my question

Comment: At the beginning I thought it was a FormType styling problem, but on your image the "Profile", "Settings" (…) are not having styling either. This may be a larger issue than only the form. I'd recommand you see what are the structural differences between your list_users templates that renders correctly and you add/edit_user templates that doesn't ; and check what could maybe be a problem in your base template (that you didn't provide).

Comment: For starters in the template you provided tags are not balanced, `.box-primary` and the wrapper `div` are not closed. And I don't know what `form_theme` are you using, but `{{ form_label() }}` helpers should already output `label` tags.

Comment: hey again ...im trying something else ..
when i modify my path like this for add user : 
127.0.0.1:8000/utilisateurnouveau it works fine the template
but when the path is : 127.0.0.1:8000/utilisateur/nouveau  after using the ('/') the template is returned incorrectly ..

Comment: @Prototype how is your style sheet referenced in your base template ? You should try using the `asset()` function of Twig in your base template. More info here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#asset

Comment: @DiabeticNephropathy thank you so much after doing some research and following the doc about asset() function my problem is solved .. my base template is missing asset() function , there is some css and js does not working where i render the template of add or edit , now its working fine ..thank you :)